# Android Issue with 'createBitmap' and Sub-pixel Data

Tags: android, android-image

I'm currently developing a small Android application to familiarize myself with the API.  However, I have come across a problem regarding sub-pixel data while using createBitmap.  I currently have these blocks of code. (NOTE: Image being read in is a 128x128 RGB565 jpeg):

```
public class MainMenu extends View {
private int vWidth;     // Width of our view
private int vHeight;    // Height of our view
private Bitmap imgButtons;
private Rect rect;
private MenuItem testButton;
private MenuItem testButton2;

public MainMenu(Context context) {
    super(context);

    // Get our view dimensions
    vWidth = getWidth();
    vHeight = getHeight();

    // Load our menu buttons' image
    BitmapFactory.Options imgOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    imgButtons = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mainmenubuttons, imgOptions);
    rect = new Rect(100, 400, 228, 528);

    // Create our menu buttons and load their specific images
    testButton = new MenuItem(100, 50);
    testButton2 = new MenuItem(100, 200);

    testButton.LoadImage(imgButtons, 128, 64, 0, 0);
    testButton2.LoadImage(imgButtons, 128, 64, 0, 64);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(imgButtons, null, rect, null);
    testButton.Draw(canvas);
    testButton2.Draw(canvas);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        super.onTouchEvent(event);

    return true;
}
}

class MenuItem {
private int xPos; // Center x-coordinate
private int yPos; // Center y-coordinate
private int width; // Button width
private int height; // Button height
private Rect rect;
private Bitmap buttonImage;

public MenuItem(int withXPos, int withYPos) {
    xPos = withXPos;
    yPos = withYPos;
}

public void LoadImage(Bitmap image, int imageWidth, int imageHeight, int xOffset, int yOffset) {
    width = imageWidth;
    height = imageHeight;

    buttonImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, xOffset, yOffset, width, height);
    rect = new Rect(xPos - (width >> 1), yPos - (height >> 1), 
                    xPos + (width >> 1), yPos + (height >> 1));
}

public void Draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(buttonImage, null, rect, null);
}
}
```

Below is an image displaying the issue:

I lied.  I'm not allowed to post images yet, so here is a link to the image:
[createBitmap issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHasV.png)

So, why is that I can display the original image correctly, but cannot correctly display images created from its sub-pixel data?  I have run the application using versions 2.1 through 3.0, and 3.0 has no issues displaying the image correctly.  Is it just an issue with devices before version 3.0, or am I missing something?  I found an article on stacked describing issues between solid images used(RBG565), and images that contain alpha(ARGB8888).  Where, my method wouldn't work if the image was of type ARGB8888, and if so I needed to physically handle the pixel data and copy the sub-pixel data myself and create my own pixel buffer for storing that data.  I tried this on a whim and it lead me down to the same issue.  I just figured why not try it?  I have also tried other variations of Bitmap.createBitmap to no avail.  At this point I'm a little stumped and figured I'd ask the community.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? It looks like you're just off the mark with your offsets, which is to be expected when one uses bit-shifting instead simple division.

Comment: Division doesn't matter in that scenario over right-shifting.  That is for the rect's position.  Further, it would only matter by a matter of 1 unit.  Which I'm not concerned about when regarding the position of the rect.

The problem is when I try to access sub-pixels of the image they're not correct.  In the provided image you see the original.  When I try to set my y-offset to 64, half of the image down (or where the black line is) I should see Test2.  Further, when I try to clip the image to just display Test1, it fails as well.


Edit: I guess I have to hit shift + enter to new line >.>

Comment: I feel like the entire Bitmap.createBitmap(image, x, y, width, height) function is hosed.  If I use: Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight) where imageWidth/imageHeight are the image width and height, I still get a messed up Bitmap.  If I use just Bitmap.createBitmap(image) it copies it fine.  I'm not sure what they're doing, but I feel like some of their functions just don't work properly in versions before 3.0 from the looks of it.

Comment: it could very well be hosed - but there's another overload of createBitmap that takes a stride width and also a bitmap type parameter. Maybe that's what you need to use here.

Comment: Also, I know the `>> 1` wouldn't cause this particular problem, but I think in general it hurts readability just so the programmer can demonstrate that he knows what bit-shifting is. :)

Comment: That's fair regarding the bit-shift; I can respect that.  I tried the method that contains stride, but I had no luck with that.  I just find it hard to believe this functionality would be missing.  I have to be missing something, somewhere.

Comment: To be fair, RGB565 is the world's worst bitmap format (it's the standard format in BlackBerry programming, which tells you all you need to know about BlackBerry programming), so I'm not completely surprised that Android can't handle them properly. Also, since I'm on a rant roll, Android is a terribly overrated OS - very immature and incomplete.

Comment: Heh.  Well, I have an Android device, and I figured it would be nice to make some applications for it.  It definitely appears... under developed currently.  Maybe once they merge into 4.0 it'll be a little better, but there certainly appears to be a handful of quirks with it.  Which sheds some light on the lacking quality of applications out there.